# How to set a media query condition that can never be met?

Tags: css, media-queries

How can I create a media query breakpoint that will never be chosen, on any device?

I've seen people use things like `only speech` or `only screen and (min-width: 1000em)` but these look like awkward cases waiting to happen. I'd also like something that is more clean and intuitive to any other developers reading the code.

Is it possible to create an impossible media query?

---

<sub>If anyone is wondering "Why would you do this?", in my case it's because I'm trying to turn off a condition in a 3rd party module which is hard-coded to do something undesirable at a certain breakpoint if a certain media query is met. Basically, it has an unnecessary wide screen view that needlessly removes useful features.</sub>

<sub>This 3rd party module doesn't let me turn off this condition or modify the undesirable behaviour, without hacking core module code which would break with future updates, but it does allow me to override its default media queries with any string. So, I'm looking for the cleanest possible impossible media query to associate with the undesirable behaviour, so that it never happens.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the OP's answer, the `not` keyword is explained in the media queries specification.

> [**2. Media
>   Queries**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0)
>
> The logical NOT can be expressed through the `not` keyword. The
>   presence of the keyword `not` at the beginning of the media query
>   negates the result.
>
> [**3.1. Error
>   Handling**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling)
>
> User agents are to represent a media query as `not all` when one of
>   the specified media features is not known.

Use of this keyword makes it easy to *"set a media query condition that can never be met"*, as requested in the question.

Here's how it works:

```
@media not screen and ( min-width: 1000px ) { body { background-color: green; } }
```

This means *in the case where the screen size is wider than 1000px, do NOT execute this code*. In other words, the media query will execute when the screen size is less than 1000px. It's equivalent to:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 1000px ) { body { background-color: green; } }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
not all
```

...logically means "not any device". It seems to work as a catch-all negative.

`not all` is often used in constructions like `not all and (some other condition)` ([dev.mozilla gives some examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)), meaning "not if the other condition is true, on any device", so it's a perfectly valid pairing.

Answer (score 2):

Matching both a low and high width can't be met so I thought about:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 123px) and (min-width: 4321px) {
  /* Never ever */
}
```